# Kendo Grid ForeginKey combobox template error in Details table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui

I trying to add template editor to the foreignkey column in the kendo grid to change the dropdownlist to filterable combobox,in the main table it's working fine but the problem in the details table once I add template editor to the foreign key it returns runtime error says

> Invalid template

here is how I assign the template editor

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.OriginID, Model.Origins, "OriginID", "OriginNameE")
    .Title(MyResources.OriginID)
    .Width(100)
    .EditorTemplateName("OriginForeignKeyEditor")
```

Comment: Can you share with us that invalid template, we can actually see in it where the problem comes from. Just check for invalid #= # combinations. Also make sure that you do not have such # symbols inside the data for that foreign key column.

Comment: What is your question..?

Comment: My question is how to change the dropdown list to kendo filtrable Combobox in the nested grid.